# Accessing app specific logging/metrics data in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure-container-service

I have a Python app running on a Kubernetes Cluster. I want to get app specific monitoring information e.g. logging info that I have in my app (using python logging module) and also metrics info that I am collecting using collectd. 
I understand Operations Management Suite can be used to monitor the cluster itself but can it also provide access to app specific logs and metrics?

Appreciate any pointers on how to do this.

Thanks
Rajeev

Comment: if your app logs to stdout/stderr, they will be captured by OMS agent which collects all container logs from Docker daemon.